# How to Pass CreateDbContext Args Parameters?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a multiple DBContexts and DesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation like below.

```
public class MasterDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MasterDbContext>
{
    public MasterDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var arg in args)
            sb.AppendLine(arg);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\debug.txt", sb.ToString());
 
        string server = args[1];
        string databaseName = args[2];
 
        string connectionString = string.Format(Constant.Connection, server, databaseName);
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MasterDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection string");
        return new MasterDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8332), I apply like this.

```
Update-Database -Context MasterDbContext -AppArgs 'LAPTOP-E4UBP70J' 'MASTER_USER'
```

But I don't see all args parameters.

Comment: I highly recommend to stay away from the Powershell commands, since they are only! available within the NPM window within VS. Get started with the dotnet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) commands today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work well at [5.0.0-preview.7.20365.15](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/5.0.0-preview.7.20365.15) version.

Adding migration with additional args:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context MasterDbContext -OutputDir Migrations\Master -Args 'P1 P2'
```

Updating migration with additional args:

```
Update-Database -Context MasterDbContext -Args 'P1 P2'
```

Here is [source](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8332#issuecomment-663749113)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools version 5.0.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/5.0.7) or newer you can pass custom 'application arguments' into the `CreateDbContext` method by appending `--` to the end of the command, followed by a space and then your arguments.

e.g. `dotnet ef database update --context MyContext -- MyFirstArg MySecondArg`

See
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8332#issuecomment-644918706 which describes how to pass arguments when using both Command-Line and Powershell commands.

> Command-Line
>
> The commands will no longer interpret any extraneous arguments as application arguments. Instead, if you want to call a dotnet ef command with application arguments, you must now put -- after you pass in all the normal arguments, followed by whatever you want to the application arguments to be. All arguments after the -- will be interpreted as application arguments. If you need to pass in an application argument which, for instance, contains a space you will need to quote that argument e.g.
>
> ```
> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -- FirstAppArg "This is all the second application argument" ThirdAppArg
> ```

Comment: Since the question is Power-Shell specific, this does not answer the question

Comment: Neither does the accepted answer; however this is an equivalent approach applicable to the original question which produces the desired result. Also, this solution is not noted against similar web searches and may be useful to people arriving here.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is only available in recent release EF Core 5.0 Preview 6

**[Flow arguments into IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#flow-arguments-into-idesigntimedbcontextfactory)**

> Arguments are now flowed from the command line into the `CreateDbContext` method of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`. For example, to indicate this is a `dev` build, a custom argument (e.g. `dev`) can be passed on the command line:
>
> ```
> dotnet ef migrations add two --verbose --dev
> ```

Comment: I installed 5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4 version.

Comment: Could you confirm the EF Core Tool Version by `Get-Module -Name EntityFrameworkCore` or `dotnet ef --version`

Comment: when I specify -Migration it works.
Update-Database -Migration migrationName -Context MasterDbContext -AppArgs 'P1' 'P2'